# Unable to load properties using getResourceAsStream in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to load the properties from `src/main/resources` folder using below code

```
final Properties oAuthProperties = new Properties();
try {
    oAuthProperties.load(TestGraph.class.getResourceAsStream("oAuth.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to read OAuth configuration. ");
    return;
}
```

but still getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream
> parameter is null     at
> java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)  at
> java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:407)  at
> com.oe.TestGraph.main(TestGraph.java:14)

I have verified that properties file `oAuth.properties` is in `src/main/resources` folder, still it is not loading

I have created project using spring initializer so Im assuming all class path is set, so then not sure what is the issue

Comment: the file is in src/main/resources folder and not in the same directory as TestGraph.java

Comment: but `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` with a relative path, called on a class, will search for the file in the same *package* (directory hierarchy) as that class - not in the source folders (which usually are not part of a deployed application) - Is the compiler copying the file to the *build* directory? if so, use `"/oAuth.properties"`

Comment: or `"/resources/oAuth.properties"` (depending where the file is copied to) - a `/` at the beginning indicates an absolute path - I am sure this kind of problem already has answers on StackOverflow

Comment: afaicr `Properties.load` doesn't close the stream, so you want try-with-resources, also `InputStream` loading doesn't support Unicode, which will need a `Reader`